# using Selenium sometimes I get index out of range and other times, no - PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a website that has a document type selector. Sometimes when running my test I get the following error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

but other times the test runs correctly.
I do not know what it could be?
[Error on Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNBcY.png)

The public website is https://onboarding.betterfly.cl/

The test page does not have the captcha but it is the same website. But the Document_Type is the same.

Here is the fragment of the STEP that call the funtion:

@When('elige el tipo de documento "{doc_type}"')

def step_impl(context, doc_type):

```
context.driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait)

selection = OnboardingLanding(context.driver)

selection.click_document_type()

selection.select_document_type(doc_type)

time.sleep(1)

context.driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait)
```

And here you here you can see the OnboardingLanding that takes the context and make de list_type of documents:

```
    def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.input_rut = driver.find_element(By.ID, "idNumber")
    self.document_type = driver.find_element(By.ID, "docuemntSelector")
    self.options = []
    self.btn_activate_benefits = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnBegin")

def click_activate(self):
    self.btn_activate_benefits.click()

def set_rut(self, rut):
    self.input_rut.send_keys(rut)

def click_document_type(self):
    self.document_type.click()

def select_document_type(self, doct_type):
    self.options = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li")
    len(self.options)
    if doct_type == "":
        self.options[0].click()
    elif doct_type == "ARG - DNI":
        self.options[1].click()
    elif doct_type == "BOL - CI":
        self.options[2].click()
    elif doct_type == "BRA - RG":
        self.options[3].click()
    elif doct_type == "CHL - PASS":
        self.options[4].click()
    elif doct_type == "CHL - RUT":
        self.options[5].click()
    elif doct_type == "COL - CC":
        self.options[6].click()
    elif doct_type == "ECU - CC":
        self.options[7].click()
    elif doct_type == "DEU - ID":
        self.options[8].click()
    elif doct_type == "GTM - DPI":
        self.options[9].click()
    elif doct_type == "HND - CI":
        self.options[10].click()
    elif doct_type == "IND - ADHAAR":
        self.options[11].click()
    elif doct_type == "MEX - ID":
        self.options[12].click()
    elif doct_type == "PRY - CIC":
        self.options[13].click()
    elif doct_type == "PER - DNI":
        self.options[14].click()
    elif doct_type == "ESP - DNI":
        self.options[15].click()
    elif doct_type == "USA - ID":
        self.options[16].click()
    elif doct_type == "URU - CI":
        self.options[17].click()
    elif doct_type == "VEN - CI":
        self.options[18].click()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please also read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At minimum, make sure you can *read* and *understand* the error message. What thing is being indexed? What index is being used? When the error occurs, how long is the sequence being indexed? Why? (Where does that value come from?) How do the page contents vary?

Comment: At any rate, we can only help you fix code that you actually show to us. If the project is *so* sensitive that you can't even show us any part of any filenames besides `.py`, then you should look for help within your organization, not on the Internet.